# button remove in datatable laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, forms, eloquent, laravel-8

i´m trying to do one button to remove one data from my database. I´m doing a form

```
public function datatable()
{
    $data = User::all();
    
    return Datatables::of($data)
        ->addColumn('action', function($user){

            $btn = '<div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <a href='.route('options.users.show', $user->id).' class="btn btn-warning btn-sm m-1">
                            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                        </a>';
                $btn .= '<form action="{{ route(\'options.users\','.$user->id.') }}" method="POST">
                        '.csrf_field().''.method_field("DELETE").'
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                            onclick="return confirm(\'Are You Sure Want to Delete?\')"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                        </form> 
                    </div>';
                    
            return $btn;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->make(true);
}
```

But when click in my button return 404 error and my URL it´s this....

```
options/%7B%7B%20route('options.users',1)%20%7D%7D
```

i don´t know that i´m doing wrong

/** UPDATE */

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'options','as'=>'options.'], function(){
    Route::get('/opciones', 'OpcionesSistema@index')->name('index');
    Route::post('/cambiarFotoPerfil', 'OpcionesSistema@changeImages')->name('cambiarFotoPerfil');
    Route::post('/cambiarDatosLogin', 'OpcionesSistema@changeLoginData')->name('cambiarDatosLogin');
    Route::post('/cambiarNombreSistema', 'OpcionesSistema@changeNameSystem')->name('changeNameSystem');
    Route::resource('roles', 'RolesPermisos');
    Route::get('users/datatable', 'UserController@datatable')->name('datatable');
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    
});
```

/** UPDATE 2 */

controller:

```
/**
     * FUNCTION TO RETURN DATATABLE
     */
    public function datatable()
    {
        $data = User::all();
        
        return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addColumn('action', function($user){
                return view('layouts.datatableActions', ['user' => $user]);
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }
```

layouts/view

```
@props('user')
    <div class="row">
        <a href='{{ route('options.users.show', $user) }}' class="btn btn-warning btn-sm m-1">
            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
        </a>

        <form action="{{ route('options.users', $user) }}" method="POST">
            @method('DELETE')
            @csrf
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

My new error it´s: Message:\n\nUndefined variable $attributes (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\clinica\resources\views\layouts\datatableActions.blade.php)"

Comment: Please share the relevant part in your `routes/web.php` file.

Comment: Your syntax is all messed up. It looks like you have all of that inside of an echo, which means the blade syntax will not work. Please post your *exact* code, not just the middle part.

Comment: @aynber thanks for your response i updated my question with all my function datatable. My problem it´s when send my form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Your `view.blade.php`

```html
@props(['user'])

<form action="{{ route('options.users', $user) }}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

your controller:

```php
public function datatable()
{
    $data = User::all();
    
    return Datatables::of($data)
        ->addColumn('action', function($user){
            return view('view', ['user' => $user]);
        });
```

and in your `web.php`:

```php
Route::delete('users', 'UserController');
```

Comment: thanks for your response but i don´t understand very well your logic

Comment: Instead of returning an html string, you can just create your own little blade-file under `/views` and then return this view. The view can receive your user because of the `@props` annotation.

Comment: ajam, thanks for your response i like it your solution

Comment: i updated my question with new problem... i don´t know this variable his location

Comment: I see, please try to change `@props('user')` to `@props(['user'])` and try again.

Comment: same error... I don´t know

Comment: i solve my problem but remove prop

Comment: Did you make sure to place your blade file into `/resources/views/components` directory? Try this and add the props again, you will need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245077/discussion-between-laisender-and-scorpions78).

Answer (score 0):

You are inside of a PHP block, which means that Blade syntax will not work. Just remove that, and concatenate the route just like you have the rest of the PHP functions, and just like the line before it.

```
$btn .= '<form action="'.route('options.users',$user->id).'" method="POST">
                    '.csrf_field().''.method_field("DELETE").'
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                        onclick="return confirm(\'Are You Sure Want to Delete?\')"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                    </form> 
                </div>';
```

Comment: thanks for your response. but return this: "error":"Exception Message:\n\nRoute [options.users] not defined."

Comment: Then you need to double-check how you have that route defined. Apparently you don't have one named `options.users`